# Introducing new divs solely for the purpose of grouping related css classes

Tags: html, dom, tailwind-css

While using  https://tailwindcss.com/, it often happens to me that a lot of utility classes land on one element. This makes the code a bit unreadable in my opinion. Example:

```
<div className="container m-auto pt-2 px-4 flex items-center justify-between md:block md:relative">
    ...
</div>
```

Is it a good practice to introduce new `div` in this example just to group related css classes and make the code more readable? For example like this:

```
<div className="container m-auto pt-2 px-4 md:relative">
    <div className="flex items-center justify-between md:block">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Does creating additional and arguably "unnecessary" elements in the DOM cause significant speed / performance / or other problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I would not add the extra `div` elements. To the best of my knowledge it would not cause significant speed or performance problems unless there were tons of them, but it seems to be adding unnecessary complexity by having elements nested within each other.

The [documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/extracting-components/) provides a few suggestions for extracting components - either extracting HTML components you're using repeatedly or extracting CSS components. Extracting CSS components has worked the best for me. The documentation's example of `.btn-blue` is a perfect case for how I've been working with TailwindCSS to prevent having 20 classes on reused elements.

```
<button class="btn-blue">
  Button
</button>

<style>
.btn-blue {
  @apply bg-blue-500 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded;
}
.btn-blue:hover {
  @apply bg-blue-700;
}
</style>
```

In the case that you do have a one-off `div` that needs a bunch of classes, I have just learned to deal with it. To help with some elements having many classes I've tried to create my own habit of grouping similar classes. For example, I keep all the classes related to margin together, all the classes that relate to padding together, etc. That way if I'm scanning a particularly long list of classes for something related to margin, if I only see `mb-4` I know that will be the only margin class without having to look further down the line.

Adam Wathan provided some [additional thoughts](https://github.com/tailwindcss/discuss/issues/181#issuecomment-427587229) on extracting CSS components. What he expresses has worked well for me. If I'm going to have one `.hero` on my entire website, I wouldn't bother extracting that CSS into a unique class. If I needed that `.hero` class on every page of the site, I'd create HTML component or CSS component.

Hope that helps!